# Как вернуть defaultdict корректно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести объект `d` словаря defaultdict  без "приставки" `<class 'str'>,` ?

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_strings(city):
    d = defaultdict(str)
    for i in city.lower():
        d[i] = '*' * city.lower().count(i)
    return d
```

Comment: `print(dict(d))` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Преобразуйте в `dict` обычный:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_strings(city):
    d = defaultdict(str)
    for i in city.lower():
        d[i] = '*' * city.lower().count(i)
    return d

print(dict(get_strings('London')))
```

Answer (score 4):

Для объектов типа `defaultdic` вы можете применить те же самые методы, как для обычных словарей, например метод `.items()`:

```
d = get_strings("Владивосток")

for letter, value in d.items():
    print(f"{letter}: {value}")
```

---

Вывод:

> ```
> в: **
> л: *
> а: *
> д: *
> и: *
> о: **
> с: *
> т: *
> к: *
> ```